# Diagonalize a Unitary matrix in Fourier domain

Tags: linear-algebra, fourier-transform, unitary-matrices

Given a unitary matrix U which I know there exists a unitary diagonal matrix D (unit circle elements in diagonal) such that DFT2(UD) is diagonal (i.e there exists another unitary diagonal matrix V such that V=FUD(F^H) whee F is the fourier matrix)

Is there a way of finding D or V?

If the answer is yes, is it also possible for rectangle matrix U with NxM (N>M) where U's columns are orthogonal?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Math.ME! For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).